# Taking screenshot programmatically doesnt capture the frame from video

Tags: android, video

I have tried to take a screenshot in android programmatically but get only a black screen. I have used the below code for take a screenshot
on a button click

```
                View u = findViewById(R.id.ytrl);
                u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                RelativeLayout z = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ytrl);
                int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
                int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
                u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);

                u.buildDrawingCache(true);
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
                u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                AlertDialog.Builder myCaptureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlayYoutubeVideoActivity.this);
                ImageView capturedImageView = new ImageView(PlayYoutubeVideoActivity.this);
                capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
                LayoutParams capturedImageViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                capturedImageView.setLayoutParams(capturedImageViewLayoutParams);

                myCaptureDialog.setView(capturedImageView);
                myCaptureDialog.show();
```

and layout file main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" 
        android:id="@+id/ytrl">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/activity_play_youtube_video_youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have used the same code with image view, and get proper result, but am not getting the proper result with a video.